# How to detect mouseleave() on two elements at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Answer can be in vanilla js or jQuery. I want to hide a div with the id "myDiv" if the user is no longer hovering over a link with the id "myLink" or a span with the id "mySpan". If the user has his mouse over either element "myDiv" will still show, but the second the user is not hover over either of the two (doesn't matter which element the user's mouse leaves first) "myDiv" will disappear from the face of existence.

In other words this is how I detect mouse leave on one element:

```
$('#someElement').mouseleave(function() {

   // do something

});
```

but how to say (in a way that will actually work):

```
$('#someElement').mouseleave() || $('#someOtherElement').mouseleave()) {

   // do something

});
```

How to detect this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$("#someElement, #someOtherElement").mouseleave(function() {
   // Do something.
});
```

Comment: Doesn't this just attach 2 separate events to these selectors? It's the same as calling them sequentially right? Or am I wrong? Wouldn't the method trigger if he hovered his mouse over element A after leaving element B? Which should not be the case.

Comment: Well, questioner used `||` (logical `or`), not logical `and`, and says it `doesn't matter which element the user's mouse leaves first`, so... my answer might be valid, but it's not clear :)

Comment: I don't know how you made that fiddle work.  i do a similar thing and get flickering behavior.    :/

Comment: John I found the same your problem. That fiddle works cause loveNoHate used the same selectors for mouseenter and mouseleave! If you use only one of this selectors for mouseenter or the divs are not near, it flickers.

Comment: The OP's question asks for a solution that will only hide an element/do something if the mouse has left both `#element` and `#someOtherElement`. @JohnP correctly points out in the comment above that this solution will hide the element/do something if the mouse leaves either `#someElement` or `#someOtherElement`. The behavior of this solution will not match what OP has asked for, where the element remains visible while either `#someElement` or `#someOtherElement` is hovered. So I would not recommend using this unless your use case is different than the OP's.

Answer (score 16):

Something like this should work:

```
var count = 0;
$('#myLink, #mySpan').mouseenter(function(){
    count++;
    $('#myDiv').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    count--;
    if (!count) {
        $('#myDiv').hide();
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pFTfm/)

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was thinking. And +1 for showing me that awesome site!

Comment: Though nice to look at, the `count` never gets updated out of the function scope. So it works like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2LNGx/. ;) Luckily.

Comment: doesn't work for me what is working was to check the e.relatedTarget || e.toElement and use the closest selector so see if we have leaved or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can beautifully use `setTimeout()` to give the `mouseleave()` function some "tolerance", that means if you leave the divs but re-enter one of them within a given period of time, it does not trigger the `hide()` function.

Here is the code (added to lonesomeday's answer):

```
var count = 0;
var tolerance = 500;
$('#d1, #d2').mouseenter(function(){
    count++;
    $('#d3').show();
}).mouseleave(function(){
    count--;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!count) {
            $('#d3').hide();
        }
    }, tolerance);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pFTfm/195/

Answer (score 2):

I think, it's your solution!!!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var someOtherElement = "";
    $("#someElement").hover(function(){
        var someOtherElement = $(this).attr("href");
        $(someOtherElement).show();
    });
    $("#someElement").mouseleave(function(){
        var someOtherElement= $(this).attr("href");
        $(someOtherElement).mouseenter(function(){
        $(someOtherElement).show();
        });
        $(someOtherElement).mouseleave(function(){
        $(someOtherElement).hide();
        });

    });
});

----
html
----
<div id="someElement">
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#tab1">element1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#tab2">element2</a></li>
        </ul>       
</div>

<div id="tab1" style="display: none"> TAB1 </div>
<div id="tab2" style="display: none"> TAB1 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While the answer from lonesomeday is perfectly valid I changed my html to have both elements in one container. I originally wanted to avoid this hence I had to do more refactoring for my clients in other html templates, but I think it will pay out on the long term.

```
<div id="my-container">
 <div class="elem1">Foo</div>
 <div class="elem2">Bar</div>
</div>

$('#my-container').mouseleave(function() { console.log("left"); });
```