# Detect when two different elements are clicked at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run some code when two different elements are clicked at the same time. Obviously we only have one mouse, but it seems like this may be possible on mobile where the user can use two fingers at once.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018749/how-to-detect-mouseleave-on-two-elements-at-once) in which a multiple selector is used to achieve this type of functionality:

```
$('#someElement').mouseleave() || $('#someOtherElement').mouseleave()) {

// do something

});
```

However, what I want to achieve is more accurately represented by using the && operator:

```
$('#someElement').click() && $('#someOtherElement').click()) {

// do something

});
```

Comment: Then you click on element event doesn't handle two elements only one, but you can handle it with parent elements

Comment: You can set some flag on the touchstart of one element and check if it is set in the touchstart of the second - and viceversa. Also set the appropriate flag to false on touchend on both elements.

Comment: with mouse you can click only then one element on top on another, but with touch i recommend use touch libraries like a hammer.js, Touchy and etc. because it's easy handle different events like a few touches and something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep track of the click with a timeout and a tolerance of the timespan between clicks you will accept. In the example below if they are clicked within 1 second of each other the logic will trigger:

```
(function(){
    var $el1 = $();
    var $el2 = $();
    var el1Clicked = false;
    var el2Clicked = false;
    var tolerance = 1000;

    var onEl1Click = function(){
        el1Clicked = true;

        setTimeout(function(){
            el1Clicked = false;
        }, tolerance);

        if(el2Clicked){
            //both are clicked within a tolerance
        }
    };

    var onEl2Click = function(){
        el2Clicked = true;

        setTimeout(function(){
            el2Clicked = false;
        }, tolerance);

        if(el1Clicked){
            //both are clicked within a tolerance
        }
    };

    $el1.on('click', onEl1Click);
    $el2.on('click', onEl2Click);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use available [Mobile JavaScript Frameworks](http://www.queness.com/post/11755/11-multi-touch-and-touch-events-javascript-libraries) or write down your custom code like [this](http://tomicloud.com/2012/03/multi-touch-demo).

Hope this is what you are looking for.