# jQuery - watch multiple items with mouseleave event

Tags: jquery, css, animation

What I want to achieve is to keep the green border visible for the active menu item when I hover over the dropdown, and it should disappear when I `mouseleave` the navigation bar AND dropdown, currently it disappears when hover moves over the dropdown.

[image]

Current JS for handling the border animation:

```
var menu      = $('.indication'),
    indicator = $('<span class="indicator"></span>');

menu.append(indicator);

menu.find('.has-dropdown, .login-status').mouseenter(function() {
    position_indicator($(this));
});

$('.navigation-wrapper .navi, .dropdown-wrapper').mouseleave(function() {
    indicator.stop().animate({
        left: 0,
        width: 0
    }, 150, function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
});

function position_indicator(el) {
    var left = el.position().left + 20;
    var width = el.width();
    indicator.stop().animate({
        left: left,
        width: width
    }, 150, function() {
        // Animation complete
    });
}
```

This code is working for the `.navigation-wrapper .navi` and border disappears as it should on `mouseleave`, but I also want to keep the border when there's an active hover over the `.dropdown-wrapper`. I tried this approach [How to detect mouseleave() on two elements at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018749/how-to-detect-mouseleave-on-two-elements-at-once) but I couldn't figure out how to make it work in my case.

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="navi-wrapper">
    <nav class="row navigation">
        <div class="navigation-wrapper indication">
            <ul class="navi">
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#1">
                        <span class="content">
                             Telefoni <span>&amp; naprave</span>
                         </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="has-dropdown">
                     <a href="#2">
                         <span class="content">
                             Paketi <span>&amp; storitve</span>
                         </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="has-dropdown">
                     <a href="#3">
                         <span class="content">
                             Internet <span>& omrežje</span></span>
                         </span>
                     </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="has-dropdown secondary help pull-right">
                      <a href="#4">
                          <i class="icon-question"></i>
                          <span class="content">
                              Pomoč <span>&amp; informacije</span>
                          </span>
                      </a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="login-status secondary main pull-right">
                      <a href="#">
                          <i class="icon-person"></i>
                          <span class="content">
                              Moj A1<span class="mobile-small">Neprijavljen</span>
                          </span>
                      </a>
                 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-wrapper">
     <ul id="1" class="dropdown">
         ...
     </ul>

     <ul id="2" class="dropdown">
         ...
     </ul>

     <ul id="3" class="dropdown">
         ...
     </ul>

     <ul id="4" class="dropdown">
         ...
     </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Please show relevant html structure as per [mcve]

Comment: Knew I missed something, additional HTML now provided. Thanks!

Comment: @charlietfl how does it imply that? `.navigation-wrapper .navi` and `.dropdown-wrapper` are two separate elements, not having any related parents

Comment: right, I missed seeing the comma...not enough coffee yet this morning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comments in code. Your code doesn't work because it's being fired when the mouse leaves `.navi`. The jQuery selector doesn't sum together separate elements. So to get around this we check if the mouse is over the dropdown, and if it is, we bind the removal of the indicator to leaving the dropdown.

```
$('.navigation-wrapper .navi').mouseleave(function() {
    // Find the dropdown
    var $dropdown = $(".dropdown-wrapper");
    // Delete any old bindings
    $dropdown.off("mouseleave.indicator");
    // If the dropdown is being hovered, wait until the mouse leaves to animate out
    if($dropdown.is(":hover")){
        $dropdown.one("mouseleavee.indicator", function(){
            indicator.stop().animate({
                left: 0,
                width: 0
            }, 150, function() {
                // Animation complete
            });
        });
    }
    // The mouse is not over the dropdown menu, animate out
    else{
        indicator.stop().animate({
            left: 0,
            width: 0
        }, 150, function() {
            // Animation complete
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: @charlietfl The mouse is no longer on `nav` though once the user moves to the dropdown. That is the behavior I believe the OP is targeting.

Comment: @dTilen Happy to hear it :)

Comment: is there any reason that the above code might not work in IE? `.indicator` animates out as if `if($dropdown.is(":hover"))` was not there

Comment: @dTilen I'm guessing IE is rendering a gap between the elements. You could wrap the contents of the mouseleave-bound anonymous function with a `setTimeout`.

Comment: `.is(':hover')` caused IE/Firefox issues so I replaced it with `.hover(function)`, which works as expected :)