# Keep the initially hidden form visible until mouse out from it in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a search icon and search form. The form is initially hidden. On mouse over on the search icon the search form should slide in. And On mouse out from icon it will slide out. And also the form will remain visible until mouse out from the form body. I have written the following -

html:

```
<li class="rightpartextra" id="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i><div class="text4">Search</div>

<div class="tools-search-form" id="searchform" style="display: none;">
   <div class=" form-horizontal searchblock" >
      <div class="col-md-9">  
         <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control searchinput" placeholder="Search Term">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">    
         <button type="submit" class="form-control submitbutton" name="submit" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and the jQuery is:

```
$("#search").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#searchform").slideDown();
});
$("#search").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#searchform").slideUp();
});
```

The code is in the page http://new.praavahealth.com/openings/3

Please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that when the mouse leaves the `#search` element (regardless if it enters the `#searchform` element) the event is triggered to slideUp the `#searchform` element.

Comment: You should use a multiple selector to prevent this behavior.  This was already explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018749/how-to-detect-mouseleave-on-two-elements-at-once

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because your mouse leaves the `#search` element in order to reach the `#searchform` element.  Depending on your layout, you could contain both in one area like so:

```
<div id="form-area">
    <ul>
        <li class="rightpartextra" id="search">
            <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> <div class="text4">Search</div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tools-search-form" id="searchform" style="display: none;">
        <div class=" form-horizontal searchblock" >
            <div class="col-md-9">  
                <input type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" class="form-control searchinput" placeholder="Search Term">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">    
                <button type="submit" class="form-control submitbutton" name="submit" ><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Then listen for your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events on the entire `#form-area`

```
$("#form-area").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#searchform").slideDown();
});

$("#form-area").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#searchform").slideUp();
});
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/oLqxt1c8/2/

Also, you can avoid reselecting the same elements multiple times by assigning variables like so:

```
var formArea = $('#form-area');
var searchForm = $('#searchform');

formArea.mouseenter(function() {
    searchForm.slideDown();
});

formArea.mouseleave(function() {
    searchForm.slideUp();
});
```

Comment: Still while focusing on input field it disappears.

Comment: You could collapse the search form on `mouseover` or `mouseenter` of an outer container or the body instead. Try replacing `$("#form-area").mouseleave` with `$("body").mouseenter`