# jQuery: detect mouseleave from two different elements at the same time

Tags: jquery

I would like to display the footer, when I `mouseover` the header, and I'd like it to disappear when I `mouseleave` from both.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018749/how-to-detect-mouseleave-on-two-elements-at-once?noredirect=1&lq=1) question, but there the OP was asking for an `or` condition. I basically need the `and`.

Here's a small [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bencarafa/hu5ekp1t/14/).

My struggle is that if I just say:

```
$('header').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('footer').css('display', 'none')
})
```

..then I wouldn't be able to `mouseover` the footer.

What's the best approach? Thanks!

EDIT: I can't wrap the header and the div together

Comment: Wrap them in a common parent and apply the mouseleave on that.

Comment: @epascarello I updated my question, I can't wrap them together

Answer (score 1):

No need for JavaScript you can just do it with CSS using a div.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}

header{
  background: blue;
}

footer{
  display: none;
  background: red;
}

.wrapper:hover footer {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>H</header>
  <footer>F</footer>
</div>
```